# Why copy ctor is called instead of move ctor when variable of type `Class &&` is used as argument

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    S() {std::cout << "default ctor\n";}
    S(const S&) {std::cout << "copy ctor\n";}
    S(S &&) {std::cout << "move ctor\n";}
};

int main() {
    S base;
    S &&ref = (S&&)base;
    S obj(ref);
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly `S obj(ref);` calls copy ctor instead of move ctor.
But if I replace this line with `S obj((S&&)ref);`, then move ctor is called as expected.

Why it happens? Why I do need the cast to call move constructor?

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29450016/827263) when you deleted it. Did you solve it? I think I have an idea what the problem is.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks for asking! Yes, it's solved. I just opened math.h and replaced `#ifndef blah` that was 2 lines above with `#if 0`. Always works. :D

Comment: Modifying system files like that is rarely a good idea. I'll post more information as an answer if you undelete the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson Done. Also, sorry for deleting the question, I didn't expect someone to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an expression, `ref` is an *lvalue*, as is any expression that names a variable of any type. So it will bind to an *lvalue* reference (for the copy constructor), but not an *rvalue* reference (for the move constructor).

Using `std::move` (or an equivalent cast expression) gives an *rvalue* expression that denotes to the object. This will bind to an *rvalue* reference, so the move constructor is chosen.