# -O1/2/3 with -std=c++1y/11/98 - If <cmath> is included i'm getting error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, mingw, mingw32

I've just updated MinGW using `mingw-get-setup` and i'm unable to build anyting that contains `<cmath>` header if I use anything larger than `-O0` with `-std=c++1y`. (I also tried `c++11` and `c++98`) I'm getting errors like this one:

```
g++.exe -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Wextra -Wall -std=c++1y -O3  -c Z:\Projects\C++\L6\src\events.cpp -o obj\src\events.o
In file included from z:\lander\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\cmath:44:0,
                 from Z:\Projects\C++\L6\src\utils.h:4,
                 from Z:\Projects\C++\L6\src\events.cpp:10:
z:\lander\mingw\include\math.h: In function 'float hypotf(float, float)':
z:\lander\mingw\include\math.h:635:30: error: '_hypot' was not declared in this scope
 { return (float)(_hypot (x, y)); }
```

Is something wrong on my side?
Or version at mingw repo is bugged? And if so, is there any quick fix for this header?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-lm` to the end of the `g++` command line?

Comment: @KeithThompson Same error. Do you able to reproduce it?

Comment: Does the problem occur with *any* program that has `#include <cmath>`, or only with programs that call `hypot()`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Any program with `#include <cmath>`.

Comment: @KeithThompson `-lm` is redundant in MinGW; `libm.a` is effectively an empty archive, with math functionality being provided by the default C runtime libraries, (either Microsoft's MSVCRT.DLL itself, or MinGW.org's libmingwex.a extension library, both of which are searched by default).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To avoid any further speculation, and downright bad suggestions such as using `#if 0`, let me give an authoritative answer, from the perspective of a MinGW project contributor.

Yes, the MinGW.org implementation of `include/math.h` does have a bug in its inline implementation of `hypotf (float, float)`; the bug is triggered when compiling C++, with the affected header included (as it is when `cmath` is included), *and* any compiler option which causes `__STRICT_ANSI__` to become defined is specified, (as is the case for those `-std=c...` options noted by the OP).  The appropriate solution is *not* to occlude part of the `math.h` file, with `#if 0` or otherwise, but to correct the broken inline implementation of `hypotf (float, float)`; simply removing the spurious leading underscore from the inline reference to `_hypot (float, float)`, where its return value is cast to the float return type should suffice.

Alternatively, substituting an equivalent `-std=gnu...` for `-std=c...` in the compiler options should circumvent the bug, and may offer a suitable workaround.

FWIW, I'm not entirely happy with MinGW.org's current implementation of `hypotl (long double, long double)` either; correcting both issues is on my punch list for the next release of the MinGW runtime, but ATM, I have little time to devote to preparing this.

**Update**

This bug is no longer present in the current release of the MinGW.org runtime library (currently mingwrt-3.22.4, but fixed since release 3.22).  If you are using anything older than this, (including **any** of the **critically broken** 4.x releases), you should upgrade.

Comment: Alternatively, substituting an equivalent -std=gnu... for -std=c... so are you saying substitute -std=gnu++0x for -std=c++0x?

Comment: @ScottF: "_are you saying substitute -std=gnu++0x for -std=c++0x?_". Yes, exactly that. The effect is to enable the semantics of the corresponding `-std=c...` option, (where that may be important), but _without_ suppression of GNU extensions, and, in particular, avoiding the specification of `__STRICT_ANSI__`.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Keith, this is a bug in the MinGW.org header.

As an alternative to editing the MinGW.org header, you can use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net), which provides everything MinGW.org provides, and a whole lot more.
For a list of differences between the runtimes, see [this wiki page](http://mingw-w64.yaxm.org/doku.php/start#version_40).

Answer (score 1):

MinGW uses gcc and the Microsoft runtime library. Microsoft's implementation support C90, but its support for later versions of the C standard (C99 and C11) is very poor.

The `hypot` function (along with `hypotf` and `hypotl`) was added in C99.

If you're getting this error with a program that calls `hypot`, such as:

```
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::hypot(3.0, 4.0)) << '\n';
}
```

then it's just a limitation of the Microsoft runtime library, and therefore of MinGW. If it occurs with *any* program that has `#include <cmath>`, then it's a bug, perhaps a configuration error, in MinGW.

Comment: The test program above should probably include `<math.h>` if it wants to call `hypot` unqualified.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I changed it to `std::hypot`.