# Compile libcurl with HTTPS/SSL

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, mingw

I'm using cURL 7.42.1 and MinGW. I'm having problems compiling libcurl with ssl support (for HTTPS). Ive tried defining `USE_OPENSSL` on `lib\curl_setup.h` but it still didn't work.

Ive been trying to find a solution to this for hours but i couldn't find one.

Comment: you'll have to show us what you are trying. Are you using a `makefile` or ??? What are the error messages you are getting. Please update your question with this information (don't post as a comment!). Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the `edit` box to format code and errors so they are legible. Good luck.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481908/kg-to-pounds-converter-build-error-clion as an example of a good question, with all the info required to help solve. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You must build `libcurl` with SSL support enabled, adding a define to `curl_setup.h` won't have the desired effect.

i.e.:

`./configure --with-winssl`

Then init curl the following way in your application:

```
if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL) != CURLE_OK)
    /* handle error */
```